# Can't fetch other users data from Instagram Basic Display API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I want to fetch media of Instagram user by [Instagram Basic Display API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user/media#reading)

But I can't because of error:

```json
"error": {
  "code": 100,
  "error_subcode": 33,
  "fbtrace_id": "AYaezQJlaXoaudxgfaDgpqW",
  "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '17841433804563064' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation",
  "type": "IGApiException",
}
```

I use Instagram Testers users, added from the admin panel. And generated token from the admin panel doesn't help.

I can fetch `/me` user, but can't fetch user by ID.

Documentation says test users don't need permission on Dev Mode

What did I miss?

Comment: Is the User ID for the same User which the token belongs to?

Comment: Hey Andrew, thanks for paying attention!

No, it is other Instagram tester User ID.

If I fetch '/me' or my user ID then it works ok.

Comment: @AndrewL just mentioned you to notify

Comment: Can you submit a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/create

Comment: @AndrewL reported, thanks!

Comment: Could you provide the link here! I can help take a look.

Comment: @AndrewL here is https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/141566711279215/